# implementing the LAMPORT Algorithm in CORBA

Tags: algorithm, asynchronous, corba, mutual-exclusion

I hope you are doing well ! 
I would like you to give me *some iformations* about how to implement the **Lamport Algorithm** in **CORBA**

Comment: Maybe start with the CORBA Programmers Guide which is available for free from http://www.remedy.nl. When you are using C++ I would recommend to look at TAOX11 (see http://www.taox11.org), much easier to use API through the usage of C++11

Comment: I have to use java

Comment: For Java look at JacORB as CORBA implementation